# Need help with post request portion of reCAPTCHA api

Tags: api, post, request, recaptcha, verification

I hardly know anything about POST request or api's , so the more explicity you can make things, the better.

I'm going through the description of adding a reCAPTCHA to my site but I'm stuck on the verification portion. Here's the part I'm stuck on: http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/verify.html

I don't know how to do a POST request. If someone could explain this portion to me that would help greatly.

Here's the code I have on my site so far, copied directly from http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/display.html#Standard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
```

```
<body>

<!-- ... your HTML content ... -->    <form action="" method="post">      <!-- ... your form code here ... -->      <script type="text/javascript"       src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=public key">     </script>     <noscript>        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=public key"            height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">        </textarea>        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"            value="manual_challenge">     </noscript>      <!-- ... more of your form code here ... -->    </form>    <!-- ... more of your HTML content ... -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why dont you use the PHP/java/perl/.. recaptcha library..it handles all you need - generating the html and validation the entered code

Comment: My server can't process php. So I'm stuck with html and javascript

Answer (score 0):

either use te recaptcha PHP/Perl/Asp/.. plugin or use the recaptcha ajax library which handles everything with javascript so you dont need server side scripts.